# Roblox Studio Save Gear

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local Players = game.Players
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local Saver = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("SaveGear")

-- This function gets the gear from its name
local function GetGearFromName(name)
    local gearContainers = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("RandomGear")
    local gear = nil
    for _, folder in ipairs(gearContainers:GetChildren()) do
        gear = folder:FindFirstChild(name)
        if gear ~= nil then
            break
        end
    end
    if gear == nil then
        return nil
    end
    
    return gear
end

-- This function loads the saved gear
local function Load(player)
    local Data = nil
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        Data = Saver:GetAsync(tostring(player.UserId))
    end)

    if success then
        if Data then
            for UserID, gearName in pairs(Data) do
                local gear = GetGearFromName(gearName)
                if gear == nil then
                    continue
                end
                print(gear.Name)
                
                gear:Clone().Parent = player:WaitForChild("StarterGear")
                gear:Clone().Parent = player:WaitForChild("Backpack")
            end
        end
    else
        error(errormessage)
    end
end

-- This function saves the gear's name to then load it after
local function Save(player)
    local SavedData = {}
    for _, gear in ipairs(player.StarterGear:GetChildren()) do
        SavedData[player.UserId] = gear.Name
    end

    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        Saver:SetAsync(tostring(player.UserId), SavedData)
    end)
    if not success then
        error(errormessage)
    end
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(Load)
Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(Save)

game:BindToClose(function()
    for _, player in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
        Save(player)
    end
end)
```

This code should save all the gear that is in the `StarterGear` of a player, to load the gear it uses the function `GetGearFromName(name)` and the gear is stored in `ServerStorage > RandomGear` Inside `RandomGear` there's some folders that contain the gear sorted by type. In total there's 3 functions `Load(player)`, `Save(player)`, `GetGearFromName(name)`.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me where the problem is and how to fix it, it does load items but it feels very random and doesn't save and load all items, I don't know why but the code doesn't save or load correctly. I have another similar code for `leaderstats` and it does work.